# Bootstrap: How to prevent sidebar and main div from collapsing when resizing page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a page that doesn't collapse when resized, but simply scales horizontally to fit. I figured out how to prevent the sidebar from collapsing (by removing @media) but now when resizing at a certain point the main content still collapses to the left, resulting in some content being hidden behind the sidebar. How do I prevent this from happening? I assume something must be written to override the default styles.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
                <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And custom CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}

.main {
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.sidebar {
  /* position: fixed; */
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    /* border-right: 1px solid #eee; */
}
.nav-sidebar {
  /* margin-right: -21px; */
 /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
  /* margin-left: -20px; */
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  /* padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px; */
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}

.main {
  /* padding-right: 40px; */
  /* padding-left: 40px; */
  /* padding-top: 10px; */
  /* display: block; */
}

.main .page-header {
  /* margin-top: 0; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
   <!--  <div class='col-xs-12'> -->
    
    
            <div class="col-xs-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 main">
                <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
                <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a working prototype, and the change is just removing the sidebar position from fixed.

```
/* position: fixed; */
```

Bootstrap will take care of the positioning into grid. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/karthik_kodali/b2h6ghyk/5/)